# Java Driver Installation for Oracle Database with Kafka Connect

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

This is the error showing in the Kafka Connect logs. I'm using Kafka-connect as connector with Debezium.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to resolve Oracle database version
    at io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnection.resolveOracleDatabaseVersion(OracleConnection.java:166)
    at io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnection.<init>(OracleConnection.java:76)
    at io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnection.<init>(OracleConnection.java:71)
    at io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnector.validateConnection(OracleConnector.java:74)
    at io.debezium.connector.common.RelationalBaseSourceConnector.validate(RelationalBaseSourceConnector.java:54)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.validateConnectorConfig(AbstractHerder.java:459)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.lambda$validateConnectorConfig$2(AbstractHerder.java:362)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/ORCLCDB
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:702)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:189)
    at io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection.lambda$patternBasedFactory$0(JdbcConnection.java:191)
    at io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection$ConnectionFactoryDecorator.connect(JdbcConnection.java:128)
    at io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection.connection(JdbcConnection.java:882)
    at io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection.connection(JdbcConnection.java:877)
    at io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection.queryAndMap(JdbcConnection.java:630)
    at io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection.queryAndMap(JdbcConnection.java:504)
    at io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnection.resolveOracleDatabaseVersion(OracleConnection.java:136)
```

And I'm using Oracle Plug-in path for connection with the Debezium for implementing CDC.

Comment: _"Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/ORCLCDB"_

Answer (score 0):

To debug it, you can try to inspect the classpath/classloader to make sure which java/class/version is being loaded. Some links below:

Check -> Troubleshooting with the jinfo Utility https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/troubleshoot/diagnostic-tools.htm#JSTGD198

JConsole https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html

And, obviously, you can check it at the OS level as well: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

With that, you might be able to confirm why you're getting the related message.